# Solve for all posible triangles that satisfy the conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Solve for all possible triangles that satisfy the conditions
How do I know if there is 2 or more triangles/
$a=30,$ $c =40,$ $m\angle A=37$

so angle $C$ I believe is $53.36$, so then angle $b (180-53.36-37) = 89.64$ so $B$ will be $49.85$
how do I know if there is more than one?

Comment: What are the conditions?

Comment: angele a 37 degree

Answer (score 0):

When you have side-side-angle of a triangle, the ambiguity comes from evaluating the angle opposite the second side.  You said $C=53.36^\circ,$ which you presumably got from $\sin C=\frac CA \sin A = \frac 43 \sin 37^\circ\approx 0.80242$  When you hit the $\arcsin$ button you get $53.36^\circ$, but you could also have $C=180^\circ-53.36^\circ=126.64^\circ$  Try finishing the solution with that and see if it works.  If it does, there are two solutions.